# pgAdmin 4 on Windows 11 doesn't load (anymore)

Tags: pgadmin-4

Haven't used pgAdmin on my machine for a while. Now it doesn't load. Tried to uninstall (just pgAdmin and PG15+pgAdmin), restart machine, re-install, re-start machine. PG15 works just fine. pgAdmin opens its main window with 'Loading pgAdmin 4...' message and never proceeds.

The pgAdmin log has this error message:

raise NotFound()
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Searching for this and other 'pgAdmin not loading' errors didn't bring a solution. Anybody ran into it or has any suggestions on what to try?

Uninstall > Windows restart > install > Windows restart

Answer (score 0):

Check your pgAdmin version if it’s pgAdmin 4 v7.4 you might want to downgrade to pgAdmin 4 v7.3 until this issue has been fixed, as everyone is currently experiencing this problem with this version.

You can follow this link to download [pgAdmin download link](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/)

Comment: Thank you! I went even further and opted for 7.0 :-) It worked.

Comment: Just in case, here're my steps (for my setup) on WIndows 11. 

1. Go to Add/remove programs, click 'Change' for 'PostgreSQL 15', select 'Uninstall individual components', select to uninstall pgAdmin. I had it installed as a part of PostgreSQL 15 install.
2. Download and install pgAdmin 7.0.
3. Voila. 

No Windows restart needed.